# An html input box isn't being displayed, Firebug says it has style="display: none" but I haven't done this

Tags: html, css

I have placed a form on a page which looks like this:

```
<form id="editClassList" name="editClassList" method="get" action="EditClassList">
    <label>
        <input name="class-to-add" id="class-to-add" size="42" type="text">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="save-class-btn" id="save-class-btn" value="Save Class(es)" type="submit">
    </label>
</form>
```

But when it get's rendered by a browser it comes out like this:

```
<form id="editClassList" name="editClassList" method="get" action="EditClassList">
    <label>
        <input style="display: none;" name="class-to-add" id="class-to-add" size="42" type="text">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="save-class-btn" id="save-class-btn" value="Save Class(es)" type="submit">
    </label>
</form>
```

For some reason `style="display: none;"` is being added, and I cann't understand why. This results in the text box not displaying.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page (or to a page that reproduces the problem)?  Is this a static page?

Comment: Probably not the issue here, but: Why the `label` tags? IMO they only make sense if you put some text after the `input` tag, which again doesn't make much sense after a button.

Comment: @jdigital I would, except webdestroya was right about it being JS related, so it's all good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might have some javascript code that is adding the `display:none;` tag after the page loads. (Or You could have that in the CSS, but I don't think Firebug would show that in the DOM inspector)

Comment: you were right, there was some old convoluted Javascript at the top of the page. I removed all the JS and it displays.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Make sure you mark the question as answered!